# How to replicate Java encryption in PHP?

Tags: java, php, encryption

Some background of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Part 1.

PHP server communicates with a Java-based device. PHP uses OpenSSL to generate a public/private keypair, then sends the public key to the device which in turn gives back an encrypted `macKey` (generated using the public key), encoded in base64. PHP now needs to base64-decode and decrypt the `macKey` using the private key.

What is the equivalent of the below Java code snippet in PHP?

```java
String base64EncodedMacKey = "LkvTT9LFj5lcxRRB8KrwwN906fSIDDcJvQK3E7a5PbR+Ox9WnslOs32jSCC9FkE8ouvr2MfWwtppuZmoPjaxwg3yAQI4UN3T1loISuF2VwKWfJ45fywbK9bNnD5Cw7336mjoGctv77Tg3JXPrsRwgMGIlBsNwdt1B0wgT4MMMAjl32TnBI3iwQ94VTMHffrK+QToddTahRHHoVsr3FVrETdiqKXdkiX1jES53im5lrXYIsY89UFkGzPo+3u4ijKIQWSLvYnA5wXI128gFHKxKYS82MbJDUn9i1RVFsGaP6T3nQRSX5SZNpSe5yGFWwMgYOx0KXMgET82FeaL2hfWuw==";
byte[] base64DecodedMacKey = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64EncodedMacKey);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keypair.getPrivate());

byte[] macKey = cipher.doFinal(base64DecodedMacKey);
```

Here's what I attempted in PHP, however I'm confused about using byte array versus string when decrypting the `macKey`

```php
$macKey = 'LkvTT9LFj5lcxRRB8KrwwN906fSIDDcJvQK3E7a5PbR+Ox9WnslOs32jSCC9FkE8ouvr2MfWwtppuZmoPjaxwg3yAQI4UN3T1loISuF2VwKWfJ45fywbK9bNnD5Cw7336mjoGctv77Tg3JXPrsRwgMGIlBsNwdt1B0wgT4MMMAjl32TnBI3iwQ94VTMHffrK+QToddTahRHHoVsr3FVrETdiqKXdkiX1jES53im5lrXYIsY89UFkGzPo+3u4ijKIQWSLvYnA5wXI128gFHKxKYS82MbJDUn9i1RVFsGaP6T3nQRSX5SZNpSe5yGFWwMgYOx0KXMgET82FeaL2hfWuw==';
$base64DecodedMacKey = base64_decode($macKey);
openssl_private_decrypt($base64DecodedMacKey, $decrypted, $privateKey);
```

The `$decrypted` above holds some binary data as it appears, so I'm unsure whether I need to convert it into a byte array or treat it as a string...

---

Part 2.

Each request has a `counter`. The `macKey` in Java code above is used to create a MAC value out of the `counter`.

What is the equivalent of the below Java code snippet in PHP?

```
int counter = 0;
String nextCounter = String.valueOf(++counter);
SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(macKey, "AES");
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
mac.init(signingKey);
byte[] counterMac = mac.doFinal(nextCounter.getBytes("UTF-8"));
String base64EncodedMac = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(counterMac);
```

The `base64EncodedMac` above is finally sent to the device to validate communication.

I've tried googling different solutions, however I've not been successful in generating a valid `base64EncodedMac` string in PHP for the device to approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself. For Part 1, I chose to use [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) to generate the public/private keys and to specify the encryption algorithm. Decrypting `macKey`:

```php
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$keys = $rsa->createKey(2048);
// [...]

$macKey = base64_decode($base64EncodedMacKey);

$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
$rsa->loadKey($keys['privatekey']);
$decryptedMac = $rsa->decrypt($macKey);
```

Followed by Part 2:

```php
$counter = 0;
$hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', ++$counter, $decryptedMac, true);
$counterMac = base64_encode($hmac);
```

The main confusing part was that in Java, HMAC was done out of byte array, while in PHP the `hash_hmac` function expects a String as its 2nd parameter, so using `unpack()` was not sufficient. However, it seems to have worked with passing the `$counter` directly. It was also important to use the 4th parameter as `TRUE` to return raw data.